# Identifying a String within a file such that it starts and ends with a quote

Tags: java, string, file

i am writing a scheme interpreter in Java.
Files contain many lines/words
This is one of the lines in the file:

> "xx'x v \"yyyyy\"... eee dddd ffff\\\n"

I have to identify it such that the whole string is returned,
but in my program, it only reads  "xx'x v \" 
and then reads the other words from " to \"
Any help is highly appreciated

```
String text = "";
    int nextString = t;         

    while(!isString(nextString)){           

            nextString = reader.read();
            int next = peek();              

            if (nextString == '\\' && next =='"'){
                nextString = reader.read();                                                     

                if(Character.isSpaceChar(next)){
                    text+=" ";
                }                   
            }               
            text += (char) nextString;
    }       
    return new StringToken(text, lineNumber);

}
```

Comment: Why not use regular expressions?

Comment: can I do this without using regular expressios, and somehow escape the  \

Comment: Regular expressions are usually faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use regular expression maybe you can use:

```
String text = "";
    int nextString = t;         

    while(!isString(nextString)){           

            nextString = reader.read();
            int next = peek();              

            if (nextString == '\\' && next =='"'){
                nextString = reader.read(); 
                text += (char) nextString;
               nextString = reader.read();            
            }     
           if(Character.isSpaceChar(next)){
                    text+=" ";
                }           
            text += (char) nextString;
    }       
    return new StringToken(text, lineNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, for example:

`[^\\]\"(.*[^\\])\"`

This will only work if the first " is not the first character of the string. The string you want is the one enclosed between (). For example, if I pass \"garbage"Hello\"foo", it will get Hello\"foo (this is what you want if I understood right).

I actually don't know how regex's Java classes handle () in regexs.

Comment: the print/return should be 
xx'x x "xxxxxx"... xx xxx xxxx\\ 
with a space at the end

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you pass `"xx'x v \"yyyyy\"... eee dddd ffff\\\n"`, which is the example you put, you get `xx'x v \"yyyyy\"... eee dddd ffff\\n`, which is what I understood you want. If not, then explain what you want better.